# Display Modal popup once for all controller/action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Need to display user agreement as modal pop up when the user visits any page from website. I have it currently implemented on Home/Index page in MVC using jquery. Since there is no authentication in website user can go to any Controller/Action method. I need to display the pop up once when the user will visit any Controller/Action. Since there are too many Controller/Action cannot add on all the pages. Any suggestion how to achieve this with common logic?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a partial in your main layout view with the pop up html and put the JavaScript with it or in a separate .js file.

Not sure if you are using core or full framework but the implementation is the same for both :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-2.1